# How to add single/multiple progress bars for concurrent download prosesses?

Tags: go, concurrency

I am trying to create one bar or multiple ones for the length of the download list, I am using goroutines to download the list really fast.
as follows :

```
if soundData.Kind == "playlist" {
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    plDownloadTracks := getPlaylistDownloadTracks(soundData, clientId)

    for _, dlT := range plDownloadTracks {

        wg.Add(1)

        go func(dlT []soundcloud.DownloadTrack) {
            defer wg.Done()
            t := getTrack(dlT, true)
            fp := soundcloud.Download(t, downloadPath)

            // silent indication of already existing files
            if fp == "" {
                return
            }
            soundcloud.AddMetadata(t, fp)

        }(dlT)
    }
    wg.Wait()

    fmt.Printf("\n%s Playlist saved to : %s\n", theme.Green("[-]"), theme.Magenta(downloadPath))
    return
}
```

and here is the download function :

```
func Download(track DownloadTrack, dlpath string) string {
    trackName := track.SoundData.Title + "[" + track.Quality + "]." + track.Ext
    path := validateDownload(dlpath, trackName)

    // check if the track is hls
    if track.Quality != "low" {

        resp, err := http.Get(track.Url)
        if err != nil {
            return ""
        }
        defer resp.Body.Close()

        dlbar := bar.DefaultBytes(
            resp.ContentLength,
            "Downloading",
        )
        segments := getSegments(resp.Body)
        DownloadM3u8(path, dlbar, segments)

        return path
    }
    resp, err := http.Get(track.Url)

    if err != nil {
        return ""
    }
    defer resp.Body.Close()

    // check if the file exists
    f, _ := os.OpenFile(path, os.O_CREATE|os.O_WRONLY, 0644)
    defer f.Close()

    bar := bar.DefaultBytes(
        resp.ContentLength,
        "Downloading",
    )

    io.Copy(io.MultiWriter(f, bar), resp.Body)

    return path
}
```

if the download quality is low the program downloads/streams parts of the playlist and appends to a file.

```
// extract the urls of the individual segment and then steam/download.
func downloadSeg(wg *sync.WaitGroup, segmentURI string, file *os.File, dlbar *bar.ProgressBar) {
    defer wg.Done()
    resp, err := http.Get(segmentURI)

    if err != nil {
        return
    }

    defer resp.Body.Close()

    // append to the file
    if dlbar == nil {
        _, err = io.Copy(io.MultiWriter(file), resp.Body)
    } else {
        _, err = io.Copy(io.MultiWriter(file, dlbar), resp.Body)
    }

    if err != nil {
        return
    }

}

func getSegments(body io.Reader) []string {
    segments := make([]string, 0)
    pl, listType, err := m.DecodeFrom(body, true)

    if err != nil {
        return nil
    }

    switch listType {
    case m.MEDIA:
        mediapl := pl.(*m.MediaPlaylist)
        for _, segment := range mediapl.Segments {
            if segment == nil {
                continue
            }
            segments = append(segments, segment.URI)
        }
    }
    return segments
}

// using the goroutine to download each segment concurrently and wait till all finished
func DownloadM3u8(filepath string, dlbar *bar.ProgressBar, segments []string) error {

    file, _ := os.OpenFile(filepath, os.O_CREATE|os.O_APPEND|os.O_WRONLY, 0644)

    // the go routine now
    var wg sync.WaitGroup

    for _, segment := range segments {
        wg.Add(1)
        downloadSeg(&wg, segment, file, dlbar)
    }

    return nil
}
```

The code works just fine but I recently added concurrency to download a playlist of tracks, unfortunately the current progress bar package I am using (`bar github.com/schollz/progressbar/v3`) doesn't support pool of downloads, after searching I found out that I can use this one : `https://github.com/cheggaaa/pb` but I don't find in the docs how to use it.

What I tried to do, is to create a pool before the playlist download and then create a bar and add to the pool, the problem is I don't have a dynamic `content-length` for the bar so I just add some constant, and it doesn't properly work!

```
pool, _ := pb.StartPool()
for _, dlT := range plDownloadTracks {
    wg.Add(1)
    go func(dlT []soundcloud.DownloadTrack) {
        defer wg.Done()
        bar := pb.New(1000)
        pool.Add(bar)
        t := getTrack(dlT, true)
        fp := soundcloud.Download(t, downloadPath, bar)
        if fp == "" {
            return
        }
        soundcloud.AddMetadata(t, fp)
    }(dlT)
}
```